# Django changing datefield to arrayField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm currently migrating my whole project to PostgreSQL. I have 2 fields that I'd like to change to ArrayField, but I encountered this error.

## Here's the former code:

```
weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## Here's what I've changed:

```
weight = ArrayField(
    models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
)

date = ArrayField(
    models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
)
```

(ArrayField is imported)

When I'm trying to use `makemigrations` there are no errors. But, when I use the `migrate` command I get this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to date[]`

Comment: does your database already contain values for those fields ?
if it's the case you need to create new "weight" & "date" with another name make a migration to convert and add the old values to the new fields and then delete the old fields and rename the new fields with the old name

Comment: It shouldn't because I created a new one

Comment: Altough Django might have added nulls to it by default. I'll check it out

Comment: Made a new DB without any data, still gives me the same  error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete my old migrations, after that it worked like a charm.